# Calculate Pecent Value from Sum of Two Columns in MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, function, multiple-columns, percentage

I am attempting to get total values from two columns (I have already done this) -- and take these values and create a percent from them. In this case I have a Weighted Value and a Total Value. I need to know what Percent of the Total Value my Weighted Value is.

I have tried:

```
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT SUM(WEIGHTEDV / VALUE) FROM test.service");

    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT WEIGHTEDV, VALUE, (WEIGHTEDV / VALUE) AS percent FROM test.service;

    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT (WEIGHTEDV / VALUE)*10 AS Percent
FROM test.service");
```

There were a few other attempts I do not readily remember.

Here is more complete code:

Login & Working SUM of VALUE

```
    <?php
                    //LOGIN INFO
                    $db_host = 'localhost';
                    $db_user = 'root';
                    $db_pw = "********";
                    $database = "test";
                    //LOGIN VARIABLE
                    $mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pw);
                    //VERIFY LOGIN INTEGRITY
                    if ($mysqli === false) {
                        die("Cannot connect to Database Server" . $mysqli->connect_error);
                    }
                    if (!mysqli_select_db($mysqli, $database)) {
                        die("Cannot select test Database" . $mysqli->connect_error);
                    }
                    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT SUM(VALUE) FROM test.service");
                    //PRINT ROWS
                    $fields_num = mysqli_num_fields($result);
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
                        foreach($row as $cell) {
                            echo "$$cell";
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
```

Working SUM of WEIGHTEDV

```
                        <?php
                    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT SUM(WEIGHTEDV) FROM test.service");
                    //PRINT ROWS
                    $fields_num = mysqli_num_fields($result);
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
                        foreach($row as $cell) {
                            echo "$$cell";
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
```

The expected output with the current totals in my Table is

```
Expected Output: %54.8
```

Test Variables:

```
VALUE: 38940.00
WEIGHTEDV:21345.00
```

Both have a type of (I changed the type to INT -- same result):

```
DECIMAL(12,2)
```

Example of actual output (directly out of the HTML table):

```
65.000000100.0000000.00000050.00000025.000000100.00000050.000000
```

Current code with above output:

```
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT (WEIGHTEDV / VALUE)*100 AS Percent
FROM test.service");
```

This is boggling me pretty good. I am sure it is something simple I am overlooking. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated as to why I cannot get a simple % value output.

Comment: Sample data and expected output would really help your question get an answer.

Comment: I stated expected output is %54.8 --- the Weighted Total is 21345.00 and the Total Value is 38940.00 -- These are DECIMAL(12,2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems you need number format and a proper `<br />`

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
      foreach($row as $cell) {
          echo umber_format($cell, 2, '.', ',')."<br>";
      }
}
```